Devanathan / Stachurski cell, hydrogen permeation in palladium
The cell mentioned in the title is a couple of electrochemical cells separated by a metal diaphragm. On the surface of the diaphragm, on one side, hydrogen is evolved. The amount that permeates is measured by oxidizing it on the other side.
I mounted such a cell with a palladium diaphragm of 0.05 mm thickness. Evolving hydrogen at 10 uA/m2 (like in the original paper) does not show any oxidation in the other compartment. Then I tried higher currents, until I observed bubbles of hydrogen, but still there was no oxidation on the other side. Like if palladium were not allowing any passage of hydrogen. The same with a palladium/silver alloy.
Does anybody have experience with such a cell? Is there any trick that I do not know?
For example: is a surface treatment of palladium necessary?

For readers, see also redox.me - devanathan-stachurski-permeation-cell-model-a
